# Mousemove not firing when any key held down in full screen + pointer lock

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, fullscreen, keyboard-events

When pressing enter on a page with the code below, the page will go into full screen with pointer lock. Moving the mouse will cause "mousemove" to output to the console. Key events work fine, though I've stripped out key events in full screen to simplify the example. My problem is that, if any key is held down and then the mouse is moved, no mousemove event fires. This is a problem for full-screen, first-person experiences since it means the user couldn't move and look at the same time! Tested in Firefox 23 and Chrome 29, 30, and 31.

**Update:** This only happens with the integrated touchpad and/or nib on my Dell Latitude E6510. If I plug in a USB mouse it seems to work fine.

Ideas on why this is happening and/or how to solve it are appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
var isPointerLockSupported = 'pointerLockElement' in document || 'mozPointerLockElement' in document || 'webkitPointerLockElement' in document;
var isFullScreenSupported = 'fullScreenEnabled' in document || 'mozFullScreenEnabled' in document || 'webkitFullscreenEnabled' in document;

function rPL(element, onEnter) {
  var pointerlockchange = function (event) {
    if (document.pointerLockElement === element || document.mozPointerLockElement === element || document.webkitPointerLockElement === element) {
      onEnter.call(element, event);
    }
    else {
      document.removeEventListener('pointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);
      document.removeEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);
      document.removeEventListener('webkitpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);
    }
  };
  document.addEventListener('pointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);
  document.addEventListener('mozpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);
  document.addEventListener('webkitpointerlockchange', pointerlockchange, false);

  element.requestPointerLock = element.requestPointerLock || element.mozRequestPointerLock || element.webkitRequestPointerLock;
  element.requestPointerLock();
}

function rFS(element, onEnter) {
  var fullscreenchange = function(event) {
    if (document.fullScreenElement || document.mozFullScreenElement || document.webkitFullscreenElement) {
      onEnter.call(element, event);
    }
    else {
      document.removeEventListener('fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);
      document.removeEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);
      document.removeEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);
  document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);
  document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', fullscreenchange, false);

  element.requestFullScreen = element.requestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen;
  element.requestFullScreen(typeof Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT === 'undefined' ? undefined : Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
}

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  console.log('mousemove');
}, false);

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13 && isFullScreenSupported && isPointerLockSupported) {
    var instructions = this;
    rFS(document.body, function() {
      rPL(document.body, function() {});
    });
  }
}, false);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The touchpad only issue is your clue. Try trapping ommousedown and onmouseup events. One of your events is triggering those behaviors so you do not want the event to fire on mouse down - just the onclick or onmouseup events.

Comment: You're suggesting that, if a browser is in full screen + pointer lock mode on this particular laptop model and a key is pressed, that moving my finger along the mousepad is causing mousedown/mouseup events that are somehow preventing mousemove from being fired.

I suppose that's possible. It's been awhile since I worked on that project and I couldn't reproduce the problem with other setups so I just ignored it. My guess is the laptop just has a deficiency.